# Branched Regular Cover over 4-times punctured sphere

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cv.complex-variables

This is probably trivial but has been bothering me all day.

Suppose $f:\Sigma_g\to \mathbb{S}^2$ is a $g+1$ fold branched conformal map with $\Sigma_g$ a connected genus $g$ surface and $f$ having $4$ branch points (all of order $g+1$).

Is it true that $f:\Sigma_g^* \to (\mathbb{S}^2)^*$ (the cover obtained by removing the branch points) is a regular cover (i.e. so the deck group acts transitively on the fibers of $f$)?

I thought this was obvious but then realized I didn't know how to prove it  (admittedly this is a bit outside my area of expertise).  Part of the problem is that I don't have a good example of a branched map from a connected surface which is not a regular cover away from the branch points.

**Edit**

Based on some comments of Sebastian.  It would be enough for my purposes to prove that the conformal structure of $\Sigma_g$ was uniquely determined by the cross-ratio of the branch points. However, its not clear to me whether this can be shown without knowing that the cover is regular...

Comment: There is also a visual proof of this fact: Topological (the Riemann
surface structure of $\Sigma_g$ is determined by the cross-ratio of the four branch images, in the case of the Lawson surface it is 2), the map is the same as the quotient by
the $g+1$ symmetry of the Lawson minimal surface $\xi_{g,1}.$ But 
this symmetry is given by rotation by $2\pi/(g+1)$ around a great circle, and one sees that $f$ is regular.

Comment: @Sebastian That's an interesting point.  My motivation is actually coming from minimal surfaces so it might make sense to think about things this way.

Comment: @Sebastian Can you expand on your comment? I'm having a hard time convincing myself that $\Sigma_g$ and $\xi_{g,1}$ are conformally equivalent when the cross-ratio of the branch points is $2$.  Maybe I am misunderstanding...

Comment: This is just a consequence of Riemann-Hurwitz and the construction of  the Lawson surface $\xi_{g,1}:$ the $(g+1)-$symmetry is isometric and orientation preserving (both on the surface and in 3 space), hence it
gives a holomorphic symmetry of the Riemann surface. By construction, it has 4 fix points, and all are of order (g+1). The quotient (as a Riemann surface) $\xi_{g,1}/\mathbb Z_{g+1}$ is the projective line.

Comment: @Sebastian I understand that $\xi_{g,1}$ has the claimed symmetry. I'm just not convinced that showing $\Sigma_{g}$ and $\xi_{g,1}$ are conformally equivalent does not depend on knowing that the cover is regular.

As I said maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: Sorry, I was to vague about this: there exists holomorphic coordinates $y$ and $z$ on $\Sigma$ and $P^1$ centered at a branch point resp. branch image such that $f$ is given by $z=y^{g+1}.$ Then, the 4 sheets are exchanged by going around $y=0,$ and such a deck transformations $\varphi_{g+1}$ extends to all of $\Sigma$ holomorphicallysuch that $f\circ\varphi_{g+1}=f.$ This topic is covered in most Riemann surface books, for example the recent one by Donaldson.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is *no*:

The monodromy group of the cover, as a permutation group on the fiber $f^{-1}(b)$ of a non-branch point $b$, is generated by four elements $s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4$ with $s_1s_2s_3s_4=1$. By Riemann's existence theorem, the question is equivalent to the following, with $n=g+1$:

> Let $s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4$ be $n$-cycles in the symmetric group on $n$ letters with $s_1s_2s_3s_4=1$. Does this imply that the group generated by $s_1, s_2,s_3, s_4$ has order $n$?

This does not hold for $n=4$: Take for example $s_1=(1, 2, 3, 4)$, $s_2=(1, 3, 4, 2)$, $s_3=s_2^{-1}$, $s_4=s_1^{-1}$. Then $s_1s_2s_3s_4=1$, but $s_1s_2=(2, 4, 3)$.

This works for any $n\ge4$: Simply take $s_1$ an $n$-cycle and $s_2$ another $n$-cycle which is not a power of $s_1$, and $s_3$, $s_4$ the inverses of $s_2$ and $s_1$ as above.

(Note: I use the right action of permutations, so in $s_1s_2$, one *first* applies $s_1$, and then $s_2$ afterwards.)

Comment: This seems pretty compelling to me, but I'm pretty confused about this stuff.

Comment: I agree that my answer was incorrect. I withdrew it. Sorry.